# How do I transfer .pst e-mails from Outlook to a Mac e-mail program?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, import, pst, microsoft-office-2011

New Macbook Pro came in yesterday with MS Office Outlook crashes consistently on importing from .pst after about 30 seconds. I see a EXC_BAD_ACCESS and something about CF get string length or the like. Tried 2 different .pst files created on different dates of different folders.

Mail and Thunderbird lack options for importing from .PST. I can export to .csv but still didn't see an option for importing that.

How can I get my .pst files into an e-mail client on the Mac?

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2454260

This is a known and fairly widespread problem.  You need to ensure the PST file is not ANSI-encoded.  Other workarounds are suggested in the above MS support article, including exporting individual PST files for email, contacts, calendar, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've used Outlook2Mac which automates the export of emails from Outlook to a form that can be understood by Apple's mail program or Microsoft Entourage program from Office 2004.